# Perforce - revert files opened by another user in my local workspace

Tags: version-control, perforce

I have a file in my local workspace that is set to an edit mode by another user. Although the workspace is longer in use, I am unable to delete it due to the opened file.

When I tried to revert the file, this is the error message:

```
jon@machine1% p4 opened ...
//depot/proj/mountain/module/moduleA.c#2 - edit default change (text) by lily@jon+mountain+22
jon@machine1% p4 revert moduleA.c
//depot/proj/mountain/module/moduleA.c#2 - belongs to user lily, not reverted
```

Is there a way I can delete this file? Revision control I'm using is Perforce

Comment: Does `p4 -u lily revert moduleA.c` work?

Comment: Tried this again, it does work. Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Bryan Pendleton has mentioned, using this does the trick.

```
p4 -u lily revert moduleA.c
```

Comment: Hi Jon, it is asking for password of the user. If the user has left the company or not available, is there another way to do this myself?